# jenkins pipleline build error:Cannot open assembly 'MSBuild.exe': No such file or directory

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use jenkins pipeline and sonarqube to analysis code. Both jenkins and sonarqube are running in docker.I followed manual:https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins to create a pipeline job:

```
node {
  stage('SCM') {
        checkout(XXXX)
  }
  stage('Build + SonarQube analysis') {
    def sqScannerMsBuildHome = tool 'msbuild'
    withSonarQubeEnv('sonar') {
      sh "mono ${sqScannerMsBuildHome}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:myKey"
      sh 'mono MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild'
      sh "mono ${sqScannerMsBuildHome}/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end"
    }
  }
}
```

when I built this pipeline,I got an error like this:

```
  Cannot open assembly 'MSBuild.exe': No such file or directory.
```

Here is the build log:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build + SonarQube analysis)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] withSonarQubeEnv
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: sonar
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ mono /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:myKey
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.0.4
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
07:36:24.082  Updating build integration targets...
07:36:24.993  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
07:36:25.387  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for cs...
07:36:25.388  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
07:36:25.592  Provisioning analyzer assemblies for vbnet...
07:36:25.592  Installing required Roslyn analyzers...
07:36:25.655  Pre-processing succeeded.
[Pipeline] sh
+ mono MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild
Cannot open assembly 'MSBuild.exe': No such file or directory.
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
[Pipeline] // withSonarQubeEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
Finished: FAILURE
```

I checked /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation/msbuild directory and can't find MSBuild.exe file.

```
[file in directory][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UcdK.png
How can I solve this problem or How can I use jenkins and sonarqube to analysis C# project
```

Comment: Why is `sqScannerMsBuildHome` pointing to a Linux path if you're running on Windows?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.My jenkins is running on a docker container which is a Linux System.I need to run .exe file in this system,so I installed mono in this container .I found out that MSBuild.exe is allowed with VS in Windows,so I had to install it in my container alone.At the begining ,I thoungt MSBuild.exe is a part of soanrsacanner,I installed soanrsacanner in container  but can't find MSBuild.exe.